# SQL Server Auth generates password mismatch on server but not remotely

Tags: sql-server

I have an odd issue.  I'm using SQL Server 2014 and it's associated SSMS (v12).  When I RDP into the server and run SSMS and try to authenticate using SQL auth, I get login failed for user error 18456, status 8, which is password mismatch.  However, connecting with windows integrated mode works just fine locally on the server.  When I run SSMS on my dev machine and connect to the server, I can log in via SQL auth just fine (but windows auth doesn't work because I'm not connected to the AD).  I have double checked my password many many times and have reset it to the simplest of strings.

Here's something weirder... when I RDP into the server and use SSMS, if I set the SQL auth user's password to blank, it works just fine!  But as soon as I set a password, it gives me error 18456, 8 again.

Side issue which might be related: SSMS 12 when ran on the server also has a weird problem where I can't use the view or table designer - it tells me that the computer must be trusted for delegation and the current user configured to allow it.  I haven't bothered with this since I can use those on my dev machine just fine.

To troubleshoot the issue further, I installed SSMS 17 on the server.  It works for windows auth just fine, but when I try to connect via SQL auth, instead of getting any error message, the login window just disappears when I click connect, but the server connection doesn't appear in the object explorer.  It's almost like the window crashes and leaves no error anywhere.  Nothing in the event viewer, and I can't find any SSMS log file on the computer.

I've tried both SSMS 12 and 17 in Administrator mode as well and it still exhibits the same behavior.

Comment: If you had a previous version of SQL installed are you sure it's the correct instance you are connecting to now? Did you have a previous version of SQL installed?

Comment: Try to connect using sqlcmd, will this behavior be reproduced?

Comment: @JacobH, it's a clean server install recently and has only ever had SQL Server 2014 on it.  That came with SSMS 12 and I installed SSMS 17 separately to try a different version of SSMS.

Comment: @sepupic I can connect and execute statements with no problem from SQLCMD

Comment: Try to clear the memorized connections from SSMS connection dialog, you can do this by just deleting entries from that dialog.  By the way, did you test sqlcmd connection with blank password? I think it may be SSMS issue only, because it caches the connection strings and can even memorize the password if you check the corresponding checkbox

Comment: @sepupic I did test sqlcmd with a blank password and it worked with the blank password.  I deleted the memorized connection strings by removing the SqlStudio.bin file, but it's showing the exact same error message of unable to log in.

Comment: @Drewsonian did you ever solve this issue? I have a similar one

Comment: @Maa421s, no I just worked around it by connecting via SQL auth remotely.  I'm guessing it's possibly a weird firewall issue where the SQL port is blocked from local connections but not from remote, but I don't have access to the firewall settings in order to verify this